# Ruby/Rails convert string to JSON -> JSON.parse produces JSON::ParserError

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails, ruby

One of the fields in my table has the JSON type so inside the model to save string there I need to do something like:

```
create(modifications: string.to_json,
       ...
     )
```

to display this on the view the `modifications` column is parsed by JSON.parse which gives me the error `784: unexpected token at '"test registrant history"'`

Long story short:

```
2.4.5 :042 > json_test = 'testing the string'.to_json
 => "\"testing the string\""
2.4.5 :043 > JSON.parse(json_test)
JSON::ParserError: 784: unexpected token at '"testing the string"'
```

why is this happening? how do you make JSON from a string then?

[Edit]

I'm on Rails 5 and Ruby 2.4.5

Comment: Rails 5, ruby 2.4.5

Comment: @dbugger That's not true - without `to_json` it will be a simple string. I know json EOD is also string but formatting is different: `"\"test note\""` vs `"test note"`. There is one similarity - the error is the same for both after JSON.parse `784: unexpected token at`

Comment: Hello @mr_muscle, Why do you use a JSON type for that field in your table? Can we have a sample of the data you expect onto that field?

Comment: `JSON.parse("\"testing the string\"")` works for me.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev it's working for recents versions of the json gem, but for older ones like 1.7.7 it's seems to throw that error. His version of rails seems to use an old version of the json gem

Comment: @Moussa: it's weird, if so. Because a string literal _is_ valid JSON. The spec is not that complicated: https://www.json.org/json-en.html. Not sure why it wasn't implemented like this from the start.

Comment: Yes @SergioTulentsev, it's weird in fact. It might be solved in newer versions. I found a solution in a post online but I would personally prefer to upgrade rails and ruby to the most recent minor version (ruby ~>2.6, rails 5.2.6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an issue on versions of json gem (<2). To avoid it you should use versions of json >2. So you might try to upgrade your rails version or just use `quirks_mode: true`.

```
JSON.parse(json_test, quirks_mode: true)
```

Here is a link to the issue on github [json issue](https://github.com/flori/json/issues/285)